# can someone explain this javascript code

Tags: javascript

This is a zoom in, zoom out function.

```
<script>
function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }
  document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}
</script>
```

I think it says, the default font size, then increase it by 1.0, then it says multiply by 0.2.
Where is the zoom out part?

Comment: It never says 'increase it by 1.0'. It only says use 1.0 as a default to begin with.

Comment: could you explain all the code in english? of what it does first then next ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a "magnifier" function, you can pass a number that increase the actual `document.body.style.fontSize` of the current document.

It rapresents:

> The font-size CSS property specifies the size of the font –
>   specifically the desired height of glyphs from the font. Setting the
>   font size may, in turn, change the size of other items, since it is
>   used to compute the value of em and ex length units.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/QytU3/

Answer (score 1):

Value passed to function `resizeText(multiplier)` will decide if it will zoom out or zoom in.

For Example :
1. If your multiplier value is position (or greater than zero) than it will be zoom in.
2. If your multiplier value is negative (or less than zero ) than it will be zoom out.

In your code if there is font size define for your current document than it will use that value else it will set to default value `1.0em`.

If multiplier value is positive this code `(multiplier * 0.2)`  gives positive result and added to your current font size.
If multiplier value is negative this code `(multiplier * 0.2)`  gives negative result and subtract some value from your current font size.

Answer (score 1):

Takes a parameter "multiplier"

If the current font size is blank/empty it is set to "1.0em"

Sets the size to [floating point value of current size, striping off the "em"] + the parameter times 0.2 and appends "em" to the end.

If the current size is not set and the parameter is 5, the font would become "2.0em"
If the current size is "2.0em" and the parameter was -1, the font would become "1.8em"

Answer (score 0):

You pass multiplier to function, which can zoom out or in depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

You pass multiplier in this function resizetext(multiplier) here multiplier is as a paramer of function.

And in a second line you check a condition

For Example :

1. If your multiplier value is position (or greater than zero) than it will be zoom in.
2. If your multiplier value is negative (or less than zero ) than it will be zoom out.

document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";

and in this line first of all you are parsing font size in a float then multiplying  multiplier parameter by 0.2em then assign a value to document.body.style.fontSize.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to change the font-size, you'll want to know the font-size.

Unfortunately, sometimes we have default values represented by empty strings. But since we know that the default value can be represented as `1.0em`, that's easily dealt with:

```
if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
  document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
}
```

If we have an empty string, we'll use `1.0em` here, because that means the same thing, but gives us a number we can work with.

Now we need to get that number:

```
parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize)
```

Note that this will not necessarily be `1.0`. If we'd started with an empty string, it would, but if there already was a value there it could be `16px`, `0.5in`, or whatever.

Now we need to change that number, so as to change the font-size of the document:

```
+ (multiplier * 0.2)
```

And then we make the number back into a number and units:

```
+ "em"
```

So e.g. if we'd called with `5` and there was no value set yet, the result would be `1.0 + (5 * 0.2) = 1.0 + 1.0 = 2.0`. If we then called again with -3 the result would be `2.0 + (+3 * 0.2) = 2.0 + -0.6 = 1.4` And so on.

There's a slight issue with the code assuming "em" ends the font-size. That's fine if this is the only piece of code affecting that value (and it probably is), but if you had to interact with other code that might set it, you'd want to check the unit and re-apply it so that e.g. `16px` being doubled would result in `32px` rather than `32em`, and so on.